# add canvas and images to dynamically created li elements

Tags: jquery, image, html, canvas

Im dynamically creating li elements with jquery. Here is my code

```
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $("#sortable").append("<li style='width:"+Size+"px;height:"+Size+"px;' class='ui-state-default' id="+"Image" + i + ">" + "IMAGE" + i + "</li>");
}
```

Now i want to add images with canvas inside each li element and the write some text again using canvas. Is it possible?

Here is the code that i wrote so far but it only adds the image to the last li element

```
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas'+i).getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "/img/test.png";
    img.onload = function() {
      canvas1.drawImage(img, 0, 0,Size,Size);
     };
}
```

Comment: Ok, any help on how i can do this?

Comment: You'll have to explain a bit more what you actually want to achieve and I'm sure we can help you.

Comment: I want in each dynamically created li to use drawImage and then be able to add some text on top of this image. I edit the original answer and added the code that ive tryed but it only adds the img on the last li

Comment: You just add an image. Why are you using canvas for this?

Comment: Because later i want to dynamically use canvas to write text on the top of each image. I think this is the only way to do this

Answer (score 3):

Closure should do the trick:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    (function(i){   //added line
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas'+i).getContext("2d");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "/img/test.png";
        img.onload = function() {
            canvas1.drawImage(img, 0, 0,Size,Size);
        };
    })(i);   //added line
}
```

The thing is when `.onload` event will be fired, the `for` loop will be already ended, and `img` will reference only the last `Image` object. In general, if variables are defined with `var`, they have function-scope (with `let`, `const` they are block-scope), and by using imediately-invoked-function-execution (IIFE), the variables become some sort of block-scoped.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some of these two solutions:

- Combine relative(li), absolute(span) and static(img) position - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/gtauB/)

```js
var i, Size = 240;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $("#sortable").append('<li style="position:relative; color:white"> <span style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px;">text '+i+'</span> <img src="/img/test.png" style="width:'+Size+'px;height:'+Size+'px; border:1px solid black" id="img'+i+'"/> </li>');
}
```

- or draw the image on canvas - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/dsz5v/)

```js
var i, Size = 240;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $("#sortable").append('<li> Canvas'+i+'<br/><canvas style="width:'+Size+'px;height:'+Size+'px; border:1px solid black" id="canvas'+i+'"/></li>');
}

var img = new Image();
img.src = "/img/test.png";
img.onload = draw_image;

function draw_image() {
    $('canvas').each(function(i){
        var context = this.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0,Size,Size);
        context.font = "40pt Calibri";
        context.fillStyle = "green";
        context.fillText("text "+i, 30, 40);
    });
}
```

The first solution is very nicely explained [here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/), the second one is based on [this html5 canvas tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/).